# Do we can able to create a daywise Snapshot in target database(redshift) as rows using debezium

Tags: amazon-redshift, debezium, spark-redshift

Do we can able to create a daywise Snapshot of table in target database as rows using debezium.

Comment: What is debezium? Have you tried it? Did you experience any particular problems? For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @JiriPechanec : Could you please provide some insights on this. 
"Do we can able to create a daywise Snapshot in target database(redshift) as rows using debezium".

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a LOT more information. For example, what is a "daywise snapshot"? What is Debezium? Have you tried to do it yourself?